# Two different sets of equations aligned to each other

Tags: equations, amsmath, alignment, layout

I have the following problem: I want to have two different sets of equations aligned. Right now I have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    1 & = 1, & 2 & = 2 \\
    5 & = 6 - 1, 6 & = 4 + 2 \\
    3 & = 3, & 4 & = 4 \\
    7 & = 10 - 3, & 8 & = 4 + 4,
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

However now I want that line (1) and (3) and line (2) and (4) align. Does someone understand my problem and has an idea? It should look something like this
[image: example image]
The problem is that if I just use align for all those lines it looks really strange because the equations in line 2 and 4 are shorter than those in line 1 and 3 and if I gather all equations instead of aligning them it becomes somehow harder to read.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How should lines 2 and 4 line up relative to lines 1 and 3?

Comment: They should be independent. By that I mean that I want it to look like I had two align-enviroments, one with line 1 and 3 and one with line 2 and 4, but now ordered the lines from 1 to 4.

Comment: Could you post a sketch of what you'd like to have?

Comment: Yes, of course. I hope you now get what I mean.

Comment: would be it ok to create three side-by-side blocks of equations, with each block containing 4 equations aligned on their respective `=` symbols?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it gets too wide in order to keep every block aligned. LaTeX complains over an overfull box in this case.